# .htaccess - Clean URL, 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: .htaccess, loops, redirect, internal-server-error, clean-urls

I've got this as my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html

# Where it's all about
RewriteRule ^users/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ users.php?user=$1
RewriteRule ^users/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ users.php?user=$1

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www.daltonempire.nl [nocase]
RewriteRule ^(.*) 
http://daltonempire.nl/$1 [last,redirect=301]
```

I tried to make clean urls, redirecting `daltonempire.nl/users/Me` to `daltonempire.nl/users.php?user=Me`.

However, I failed miserably. My website now constantly returns a `500 Internal Server Error`.
(I possibly somehow created a redirection loop?)

What did I do wrong? (And what do I have to do to fix it?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe you have an extra newline in last rule. Also make sure to use `L` (Last) flag in all of your rules.

```
RewriteEngine on 

# Where it's all about
RewriteRule ^users/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ users.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f 
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(daltonempire\.nl)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: That does solve the 500 Error for my whole website. However, I still get the 500 error when I go to `daltonempire.nl/users/me` (which _should_ redirect me to `daltonempire.nl/users.php?user=me`)                                                           Aside from that, what does the `L` flag then do?

Comment: Thank you! (But still, what does the `L` flag do?)

Comment: You're welcome. `L` is for Last rule that injects the resulting URI again for Apache to evaluate.